# Using docker on another PC when using docker-compose in Visual Studio

Tags: docker, visual-studio

I' developing a `blazor` app in Visual Studio, with one frontend and some microservices. I'm using `docker-compose` project in order to build and run all at once, and it works on my PC.

Now we have a Ubuntu server machine available over the network, with `docker` installed, and I'd like to use that machine instead of my own pc for building and running containers, due to performance issues of my laptop.

What I need to do in order to tell Visual Studio to use `docker` of another machine in order to build and test the solution containers?